# Setting up conditional formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with conditional formatting set in columns `M` & `N`. 
These columns are set IF column `K` is over 250, then it divides column `K` 
in 1/2. Also, in column `M` it will add column I in addition to the 1/2 amount.

On rows where this doesn’t exit, it still adds column I and I can’t figure out how to have column `M` show `0` rather than `4` as shown in the example below.

Is it possible to get `M` to show `0` on the second row in this case?

[image: example of rows/columns]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1390573/edit) to give us the actual formulas used. Also, I am not sure but I get the feeling you are not talking about [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67) but just plain [formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-formulas-in-Excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173).

Comment: "M3" =IF($K3>250,$K3/2,0)+I3 ---- "N3" =IF($K3>250,$K3/2,0)

Comment: "M4" =IF($K4>250,$K4/2,0)+I4 --- "N4" =IF($K4>250,$K4/2,0)

Comment: These are the M & N formulas

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the addition of `I3` into the `IF` formula:

```
=IF($K3>250,$K3/2+I3,0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Have a great day!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @GregNelson - If this works for you, you can flag this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.